# How can I get a set of values from a value in a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, set

I have a map that contains values which could exist for multiple keys.  So I figured I needed to setup a map like this:  `Map<Integer, Set<Long>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, Set<Long>>`

I would like to retrieve a value from a key's set of values.

The problem is that I don't know how to add a `long` value to the set in `myMap` and I don't know how to check if `myMap` contains a value in it's values' set.

Is this implementation incorrect?

Comment: Just `map.get(key).add(newValue)` and `map.get(key).contains(value)`? What exactly is the trouble you've with it?

Comment: Perhaps a silly question, but what `key` would I be getting if I'm adding my first key value pair?

Comment: I think it's time to read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

Comment: @BalusC I've read that before, but I guess I just don't understand.  Is that `Set<Long>` in `myMap` cannot be modified once added to `myMap`?

Comment: How exactly did you come to that conclusion? Perhaps you're just asking the question the wrong way. If you're unable to modify it, then you should instead be asking a question about exactly that problem instead of asking a more generic question which is already answered in Oracle's own tutorial and the javadoc.

Comment: @BalusC I'm going to modify my question and hope it's more clear.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for your patience, as I was editing my question and typing up the results I wanted to produce I began to see what I needed to do based on your suggestions.

Comment: If third-party libraries are fair game, you might find it more convenient to use a [`SetMultimap`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap) from Guava.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
if(myMap.containsKey(myKey)){
    myMap.get(myKey).add(value);
}
```